# Python: memory consuption when passing data to a function vs. loading within the function

Tags: python, pandas, function, memory

I am working with a large dataset, in Python2, loading it via pandas. Occasionally the execution is spontaneously killed - likely to due to the high memory consumption. Thus I am trying to make my code more efficient in terms of not duplicating data in new variables, eliminating the variables that are no more needed, etc.

I currently load dataset and then pass the data to a function that operates on it:

```
def func(df):
    do something
    return result

df = pd.read_csv(path_to_data)
func(df)
```

I wonder whether there is any advantage (memoriwize) in loading the dataset within the function:

```
def func(path to data):
    df = pd.read_csv(path_to_data)
    do something
    return result

func(path_to data)
```

Other tips on optimizing memory use with python and pandas would be appreciated as well.

Comment: In my understanding there is no difference between the two options. You can look into using [categorical data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) to save memory.

Comment: When you call *func(df)* you do not pass the data by value - i.e., it's just a reference and thus there is no significant additional memory consumption. Given your problem description I suspect that the issue is entirely down to the size of the dataframe

Comment: Three suggestions: look at 'do something' to see how it can be optimized if you can load the DF into memory; if the processing allows then read the CSV in chunks, process, write out; consider Polars instead of Pandas for large data.

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @user19077881 I repeatedly sample rows from a dataset with 8 million rows and a thousand columns - I thought about loading only the sampled rows, but it might be very slow when doing repeatedly. I could however completely abandon pandas in the main algorithm, using only numpy - would polars give any advantage, if used only to load the dataset?

Comment: You might find something useful in the guidance on Pandas for large data [See Link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/scale.html). It really depends on how you are processing the data. Polars can do the same as Pandas, uses labelled columns,  but the syntax is in places somewhat different; the benefits are that is it faster (in some cases much faster) and can handle large datasets. Here is a brief summary of Polars [Link](https://www.datacamp.com/blog/an-introduction-to-polars-python-s-tool-for-large-scale-data-analysis) and the official documentation is good.